# Use composite primary key and autoincrement one column if null

Tags: sqlite, triggers, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE methods (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    version INTEGER NOT NULL,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,version)
    );
```

I would like the column `id` to auto-increment when null on a new row. I would also like the column `version` to be set to 1. I would like to store the auto-increment value in `sqlite_sequence`. When a row is inserted with `id` I would like `version` to increase by 1.

I have this at application level but need it at the database level and understand I will have to create a trigger or two.

Comment: Did you *try* to create a trigger?

Comment: No. I am not an expert at SQL, so I thought I would ask first, then try.

Comment: You'll get more useful responses if you try first. Posting your requirements and asking others to write code for you won't get you very far here on SO.

Comment: Do you know how to get the highest value of version for a specified id?

Comment: It is not prudent to represent your major version value with an auto-incrementing ID.  Assigning any "meaning" to a primary key, especially an auto-incrementing integer, is generally considered not robust design.

Comment: @Tim So, I should change it to a UNIQUE KEY and use ROWID to reference each row?